# A question about rearranging order of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a$ be limit point of sequence of $\{x_n\}$ ,let $\{y_n\}$ be a sequence obtained by rearranging the order of the term of $\{x_n\}$ adding a finite or infinite number of additional terms .prove that $a$ is limit point of $\{y_n\}$

I don't have any idea of all the sides please help me

Comment: @MeesdeVries,,i was miss the class

Comment: @MeesdeVries..can you help it i was studying but i dont understand concept

Answer (score 0):

Consider the definition of a limit point: A point $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of a numerical sequence $(a_n)$ if, $\forall \epsilon > 0, \{n: |a_n - x| \leq \epsilon\}$ is infinite.

So in your problem setup, there are infinitely many terms in $x_n$ that are arbitrarily close to $a$. To make it concrete, let's arbitrarily pick an $\epsilon^* > 0$. Since $a$ is a limit point of $(x_n)$, there are infinitely many terms in $x_n$ s.t. $|x_n - a| \leq \epsilon^*$.

Let $S = \{x_n: |x_n - a| \leq \epsilon^*\}$.

What is the intersection of $S$ and the set of elements of $y_n$?

Comment: @ken47..sorry youe answer is dufficulty to undertand

Comment: Let's make this even more concrete. The fact that $a$ is a limit point of the sequence $(x_n)$ means that there are infinitely terms of $(x_n)$ such that $|x_n - a| \leq 1$. In other words, there are infinitely many terms that are within 1 unit of $a$. 

But this is not just true for 1. The definition of a limit point says that you can pick any positive number, called $\epsilon$, and there will be infinitely many terms of $(x_n)$ that are within $\epsilon$ units of $a$.